# Lombok interactive behaviour in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok

I'm curious how actually [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) works with Eclipse (or any other IDE). What I have found is that since version 0.10 they abandon `AbstractProcessor` for `ECJ` and stay completely with javaagent and bytecode modification.

This works well if I use some editor without syntax checking + `javac` with `-javaagent` but for Eclipse it's impossible as if I add `-javaagent` to build configuration it's no used during incremental build with internal `ECJ`. And therefore if you for instance use some method which not exist in code (but will after bytecode instrumentation) it simply throws error.

My question is: How this is handle that method which do not exist in code are visible in it without any error?

UPDATE:

Due to **chrylis** information about methods being taken from .class file my question can be shortened to following I think:

How use -javaagent + objectweb.asm/javaassist/etc. with automatic build in Eclipse so generated method/fields/etc. would be available through code completion, method outliner, etc.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking, but if you're talking about autocompletion, as long as the synthesized methods are present in the `.class` file, Eclipse has them available for autocomplete.

Comment: @chrylis I guess it useful information but still not solve my problem, so I made an update to question.

Comment: It's still unclear what you're asking; are you saying that your Lombok additions don't work when using the Eclipse compiler? Do you have the Lombok Eclipse plugin installed?

Answer (score 4):

The IDE you use to create the java models using lombok annotations need to include some sort of plugin to handle the methods generated by lombok.

To include the plugin in different IDE's and packaging managers, see this link for more information: http://projectlombok.org/download.html

- `Maven` or `Ivy` : Lombok is in maven central. More…
- `Javac` : Just put lombok.jar on the classpath.
- `NetBeans` : Just put lombok.jar on the classpath and enable annotation processing. More…
- `Eclipse and variants` : Run lombok.jar as a java app (i.e. doubleclick it, usually) to install. Also add lombok.jar to your project. Supported variants: Springsource Tool Suite, JBoss Developer Studio
- `IDEA IntelliJ` : A plugin developed by Michael Plushnikov adds support for most features.
- `Javadoc` : First delombok your code then run javadoc on the result. More…
- `Android` : The proper way to use lombok with android is somewhat complicated but possible. More…
- `GWT` : Lombok works with GWT. More…
- `Play!` : Framework   Use Aaron Freeman's lombok play plugin.
- `ecj` : Lombok works on ecj and ecj-based tools. More…